# Transform fields into rows without a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, view, pivot, common-table-expression

In a legacy table in sql server 2005 I have settings for a customizable grid of data defined like this

```
TotalColumn (int, null)
Column1Name (char(12), null)
Column2Name (char(12), null)
Column3Name (char(12), null)
Column4Name (char(12), null)
Column5Name (char(12), null)
Column1Type (int, null)
Column2Type (int, null)
...
```

Where TotalColumn is an integer 0-5 noting which column is totaled. Instead of building an object model to mimic this, I want to convert this data into a list of column definitions, ordered by their index, like this

```
public class LedgerColumn
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LedgerColumnType ColumnType { get; set; }
    public bool IsTotaled { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do so without using a stored procedure.  In the past I have done data manipulation using [cte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and then pivot the data in a view.  I'm just not sure how to go about splitting the fields out into rows without doing something like

```
SELECT
    Column1Name,
    Column1Type,
    ...
FROM
    MyTable

UNION

SELECT
    Column2Name,
...
```

Something tells me there has to be a better way, I'm just not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting to do the opposite of a Pivot - an Unpivot! They can be somewhat confusing, but I think that's what you're looking for.

From [MSDN's TSQL Pivot and Unpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

> UNPIVOT performs the opposite operation to PIVOT by rotating columns
>   of a table-valued expression into column values.